# How can I have two structures for footnote in two separated lines?

Tags: footnotes, footmisc, para

I want this `first` structure with `\footnote` command to be with  `para` option footnote.
And for the `second` structure with `\footnotetext` command, I want it to be in the `next line` and also to be with  `para` option footnote.
I mean each structure to be in a `separated line`. How can I do this?
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
I want all of this structures to be with  para option footnote.
Hi\footnote{hello}.I am fine\footnote{Okay}.
And I want all of the below structures to be in the next line and also to be with  para option footnote.
\footnotemark\footnotetext{First footnote}
\footnotemark\footnotetext{Second footnote}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this as a separate answer because it is a completely different approach:

When a footnote is inserted in para mode, a `\hbox` is put into `\footins`, which will later be `\unhbox`ed. So the width of this `\hbox` is irrelevant and can be used as a marker, into which block the footnote belongs:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
% This is almost an exact copy from footmisc.sty
\renewcommand\@footnotetext[1]{%
  \insert\footins{%
    \ifFN@setspace
      \let\baselinestretch\FN@baselinestretch
    \fi
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox
    \floatingpenalty\@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \setbox\FN@tempboxa=\hbox{%
        \@makefntext{\ignorespaces#1\strut
          \penalty-10\relax
          \hskip\footglue
        }% end of \@makefntext parameter
      }% end of \hbox
      \dp\FN@tempboxa=0pt
      \ifFN@etex
        \ht\FN@tempboxa=\dimexpr\wd\FN@tempboxa *
                        \footnotebaselineskip / \columnwidth\relax
      \else
        \ht\FN@tempboxa=\fudgefactor\wd\FN@tempboxa
      \fi
      % The following line was inserted here
      \wd\FN@tempboxa=\footnotetype
      \box\FN@tempboxa
    \color@endgroup
  }%
  \FN@mf@prepare
}
% This is almost an exact copy from footmisc.sty except for the \FN@tempboxc parts
\long\def\makefootnoteparagraph{\unvbox\footins \makehboxofhboxes
  \setbox\FN@tempboxa=\hbox{\unhbox\FN@tempboxa \removehboxes}
  \setbox\FN@tempboxc=\hbox{\unhbox\FN@tempboxc \removehboxes}
  \hsize\columnwidth
  \@parboxrestore
  \baselineskip=\footnotebaselineskip
  \noindent
  \rule{\z@}{\footnotesep}%
  \ifdim\wd\FN@tempboxa=0pt\else%
    \unhbox\FN@tempboxa\par
  \fi%
  \ifdim\wd\FN@tempboxc=0pt\else%
    \unhbox\FN@tempboxc\par
  \fi%
}
% This is almost an exact copy from footmisc.sty except for the \FN@tempboxc parts
\def\makehboxofhboxes{\setbox\FN@tempboxa=\hbox{}\setbox\FN@tempboxc=\hbox{}%
  \loop
    \setbox\FN@tempboxb=\lastbox
    \ifhbox\FN@tempboxb
    \ifdim\wd\FN@tempboxb=0sp%
      \setbox\FN@tempboxa=\hbox{\box\FN@tempboxb\unhbox\FN@tempboxa}%
    \else%
      \setbox\FN@tempboxc=\hbox{\box\FN@tempboxb\unhbox\FN@tempboxc}%
    \fi%
  \repeat
}
\newdimen\footnotetype
\let\mfn@orig@footnote\footnote
\renewcommand*\footnote{\footnotetype=0sp\relax\mfn@orig@footnote}
\let\mfn@orig@footnotetext\footnotetext
\renewcommand*\footnotetext{\footnotetype=1sp\relax\mfn@orig@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
I want all of this structures to be with  para option footnote.
Hi\footnote{hello}.I am fine\footnote{Okay}.
And I want all of the below structures to be in the next line and also to be with  para option footnote.
\footnotemark\footnotetext{First footnote}
\footnotemark\footnotetext{Second footnote}
Hi\footnote{Another hello}.I am fine\footnote{This gets boring}.
\end{document}
```

[image: The output]

This approach could be easily extended to much more than two groups of footnotes.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by inserting a newline between the footnotes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\newcommand\footnotebreak{\insert\footins{\newline}}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
I want all of this structures to be with  para option footnote.
Hi\footnote{hello}.I am fine\footnote{Okay}.
\footnotebreak%
And I want all of the below structures to be in the next line and also to be with  para option footnote.
\footnotemark\footnotetext{First footnote}
\footnotemark\footnotetext{Second footnote}
\end{document}
\newcommand\footnotebreak{\insert\footins{\hbox{\newline}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks my dear Marcel Krüger, but I didn't mean it. It doesn't work for the below structure. Hi\footnote{hello}.I am fine\footnote{Okay}.
\footnotebreak%
\footnotemark\footnotetext{First footnote}
\footnotemark\footnotetext{Second footnote}
I want to  the below structure return to first line(not second line) because it is written by \footnote{ee} command.
Hi\footnote{hello}.I am fine\footnote{Okay}
And also I want to the below structure return to second line (not third line) because it is written by 
\footnotebreak
\footnotemark\footnotetext{er}command.

Comment: @  Marcel Krüger  Actually i want two separated structure. The first structure in one line (may be more than line) and the second structure to be in the other line (may be more than line)