Alignment of multi-line footnotes with margin
I have the following simple example with a multi-line footnote. I want the footnote number to be aligned with the margin and the second line to also be aligned with the margin, i.e., essentially aligned with the footnote number.
Using this code, the footnote is fine from the second line:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
    Some text\footnote{
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}
\end{document}


However, the first line is not aligned with the margin. This could be achieved with \usepackage[hang]{footmisc}. The problem is that although this sets the first line correctly, the second line is then not aligned with the margin but with the text of the first line:

Is there an easy way to resolve this?

EDIT: This shows the problem with multiple footnotes when using \usepackage[para]{footmisc}:
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc} 

\begin{document}
    Some text\footnote{
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}
        
    Some more text\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
        
        
\end{document}


It can be seen that the footnote starts in line with the end of the first footnote, but ideally should start in a new row. Apparently, it appears that in my full text sometimes the footnote starts in a new row and sometimes in line with the previous footnote.

Also related: How to remove indentation in footnote? or Footnote indent equal to text parindent

You can use package scrextend and its command \deffootnote to configure the format you want:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[1em]{0em}{1em}{%
\makebox[1em]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\hfill}%
}
\begin{document}
    Some text\footnote{%
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}
\end{document}


BTW: I would also remove the \textsuperscript, because a number in \footnotesize is already small enough and the superscript is not needed at the footnote apparatus:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[1.5em]{0em}{1em}{%
  \makebox[1.5em]{\thefootnotemark\hfill}%
}
\begin{document}
    Some text\footnote{%
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}
\end{document}



First time, I heard about this package, nice

@MadyYuvi There are a lot of nice features in KOMA-Script. ;-)

@MadyYuvi BTW: Here are several examples for footnotes with scrextend: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198766/277964

\usepackage[para]{footmisc} may suits for you.
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

    Some text\footnote{
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}
\end{document}



I really like this solution. However, I realized that sometimes footnotes are not necessarily starting on a new row. This seems to be also related to this question but there appears to be not an easy solution to fix it. Do you have any ideas on this?

@carl Do you mean a footnote having many paragraphs? Sorry, not understand correctly

I meant multiple footnotes that go potentially over multiple rows. For example, when you add in the code above after the first footnote Some more text\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}. Then the footnote will be placed in the same line as the end of the first footnote, but ideally I want to have every footnote starting on a new line.

Sorry, I've tried what you posted, but working fine, can you provide the MWE which produced the error as you mentioned

I added now the MWE.

Is it  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418974/how-can-i-have-two-structures-for-footnote-in-two-separated-lines/419437#419437 helpful  for you?

This could work, but i wondered if there is a more direct solution when loading, e.g., the package. But this doesn't seem to be the case. But thanks for looking into it.
